# How to ignore certain values and print the rest using jq cmd

Tags: jq

Here I'm trying to write jq command that should ignore the message `check failed for material:` and `Error while scheduling`, and print the rest.

The other values which I'm trying to print will get changing at every time. But these msg will remain constant (`check failed for material:`, `Error while scheduling`). We need to write a jq cmd that should ignore the mentioned message and print the rest/changing content.
Please let me know if I'm not clear.
Thanks in Advance !

```json
[
   {
      "message":"check failed for material:",
      "detail":"Error performing",
      "level":"ERROR"
   },
   {
      "message":"check failed for material:",
      "detail":"Error performing command",
      "level":"ERROR"
   },
   {
      "message":"Error while scheduling",
      "detail":"Maximum limit reached",
      "level":"ERROR"
   },
   {
      "message":"Error while scheduling",
      "detail":"Maximum limit reached",
      "level":"ERROR"
   },
   {
      "message":"Duplicate error",
      "detail":"Found a mapping value where it is not allowed",
      "level":"ERROR"
   },
   {
      "message":"Invalid Merged Configuration",
      "detail":"Number of errors: 44",
      "level":"ERROR"
   }
]
```

On jqplay: https://jqplay.org/s/tCYiua9KzH

Desired output:

```json
[
   {
      "message": "Duplicate error",
      "detail": "Found a mapping value where it is not allowed",
      "level": "ERROR"
   },
   {
      "message": "Invalid Merged Configuration",
      "detail": "Number of errors: 44",
      "level": "ERROR"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map(select(
   .message |
   contains("check failed for material:") or contains("Error while scheduling") |
   not
))
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/qWuHx_nddk)

Or for exact matches,

```
map(select(
   .message |
   . != "check failed for material:" and . != "Error while scheduling"
))
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/WvN9_D_Q2Q)

- We don't want to eliminate the array, so we use `map` instead of `.[]`. (Alternatively, we could keep using `.[]` but wrap the whole in `[ ... ]`.)
- `contains(A, B)` check if both A and B are contained, rather than either.
- And `not` negates the condition so we can eliminate the matching records instead of keeping them.